# AOSP art.module.platform.api.stubs compile failed (NaN java error)

Tags: java, android, nan, android-source, lineageos

```
Failed to build aosp
[  0% 18/12890] //libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api:art.module.platform.api.stubs javac [common]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/art.module.platform.api.stubs/android_common/javac/art.module.platform.api.stubs.jar

out/soong/.intermediates/libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/art.module.platform.api.stubs/android_common/javac/srcjars/java/lang/Double.java:106: error: self-reference in initializer
public static final double NaN = NaN;
                                 ^
out/soong/.intermediates/libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/art.module.platform.api.stubs/android_common/javac/srcjars/java/lang/Float.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
public static final float NaN = NaNf;
                                ^
  symbol:   variable NaNf   
  location: class Float
2 errors
```

In every file Double.java file NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
After I am trying to modify theese files, build regenerate them with same error.
Where is this files locate in sources and how to fix theese errors?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

They are from metalava.

File `src/main/java/com/android/tools/metalava/model/FieldItem.kt`

I bet you've updated kotlinc so the code now doesn't work as expected. There are two sections there. One for Double and one for Float. Both don't work as expected with kotlin 1.5+

So you should replace

```
is Float -> {
  writer.print(" = ")
  when (value) {
     Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(1.0f/0.0f);")
     Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(-1.0f/0.0f);")
     Float.NaN -> writer.print("(0.0f/0.0f);")
  }
}
```

by

```
is Float -> {
  writer.print(" = ")
  when {
    value == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(1.0f/0.0f);")
    value == Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(-1.0f/0.0f);")
    java.lang.Float.isNaN(value) -> writer.print("(0.0f/0.0f);")
    else -> { 
      writer.print(canonicalizeFloatingPointString(value.toString()))
      writer.print("f;")
    }
  }
}
```

and same for Double, replace the block

```
 is Double -> {
   writer.print(" = ")
   when (value) {
     Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(1.0/0.0);")
     Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(-1.0/0.0);")
     Double.NaN -> writer.print("(0.0/0.0);")
     else -> { 
       writer.print(canonicalizeFloatingPointString(value.toString()))
       writer.print(";")
     }
   }
 }
```

by

```
 is Double -> {
     writer.print(" = ")
     when {
         value == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(1.0/0.0);")
         value == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY -> writer.print("(-1.0/0.0);")
         java.lang.Double.isNaN(value) -> writer.print("(0.0/0.0);")
         else -> {
             writer.print(canonicalizeFloatingPointString(value.toString()))
             writer.print(";")
         }
     }
 }
```